# How to get enum value

Tags: python, enums, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.mouse import Button
from enum import Enum

value=Key.esc
def corresponding_event(key):
    print(type(key))
corresponding_event(value)
```

produces <enum 'Key'>

How would I obtain the value for the enum 'Key'and also check if it's an enum the function can pass different type of values as well.
<enum 'Button'> ,<enum 'Key'> ,<class 'str'> ,<class 'int'>

I know you can check for enums with

```
if isinstance(key,Enum):
    print(key.name,key.value)
```

I would like to do different actions if it's a key or button.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Your question is titled "How to get enum value" but the body shows you using `key.value` so you seem to know how to do that. Also, have you looked at the example here: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check for it with `isinstance`

```py
from enum import Enum


class Key(Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3


class Button(Enum):
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = 30


def some_func(x):
    if isinstance(x, Key):
        print('Key', x.value)
    if isinstance(x, Button):
        print('Button', x.value)


k = Key(1)
b = Button(20)

some_func(k)
some_func(b)
```

If your function can get all sorts of different types and you need to do things depending on the type you need to check for types, no real way around it.

I am not sure what your exact questions is, but form what you wrote just checking via `isinstance(x, Key)` and `isinstance(x, Key)` is what you want, getting the value form an enum is also just `.value`. So in general you already more or less wrote what you need.